# No se muestra template al heredar en jinja

Tags: python, html5, flask

Estoy tratando de incluir en mi html un formulario usando un template de jinja. El problema es que no se renderiza el contenido.

Asi es la estructura de mi directorio de templates

```
  templates/
     |------ base.html
     |------ formulario.html
     |------ index.html
```

base.html: Administro el contenido de **head** y las dependencias y creo una referencia al bloque **index** y al bloque **title**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    {% block title %} {% endblock title %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/normalize.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}">
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/app.js') }}"></script>
</head>
    {% block index %} {% endblock index %}
</html>
```

index.html:  indico que voy a extender **base.html** y declaro mi bloque ***index** y **title** luego creo la referencia al bloque **formulario**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} <title>Consultador de jugadas</title> {% endblock title %}

{% block index %}
<body>
    <div class="contenedor">
        {% block formulario %}{% endblock formulario %}
    </div>
</body>
{% endblock index %}
```

formulario.html: extiendo **index.html** y creo el bloque formulario

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% block formulario %}
        <div class="formulario">
            <h1 class="formulario__titulo">Consultar Jugada</h1>
            <p class="formulario__descripcion">Introduce el numero para comprobar si tiene premio</p>
            <form class="formulario__cuerpo" method="post" action="{{ url_for('revisar_jugada')   }}">
                <input class="formulario__cuerpo--input" type="text" id="numero" name="numero" min="0" max="9999" title="Ingrese un número de 4 dígitos" required>
                <div class="formulario__cuerpo--opciones">
                    <div class="formulario__cuerpo--opcion">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="opcion" value="1" checked>
                        <label for="c2">Dos cifras</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="formulario__cuerpo--opcion">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="c3" name="opcion" value="2" checked>
                        <label for="c3">Tres cifras</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="formulario__cuerpo--opcion">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="prov" name="opcion" value="provincia" checked>
                        <label for="prov">Provincia</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="formulario__cuerpo--opcion">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="nac" name="opcion" value="nacion" checked>
                        <label for="nac">Nacion</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="formulario__cuerpo--opcion">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="cord" name="opcion" value="cordoba" checked>
                        <label for="cord">Cordoba</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input class="btn btn--submit" type="submit" value="Comprobar">
            </form>
        </div>
{% endblock formulario %}
```

Cuando levanto el servidor solo se ve renderizado el codigo html correspondiente a todo los bloques menos el de formulario y no logro entender por que se comporta asi.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>Consultador de jugadas</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/styles.css">
    <script src="/static/js/app.js"></script>
</head>
    
<body>
    <div class="contenedor">
        
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Intenta solo usando {% endblock %} en vez de {% endblock formulario %} al final del bloque

Comment: Eso ya lo probe  sigue sin funcionar, según la documentación es recomendable agregar que bloque finaliza para mejorar la legibilidad por lo cual no debería ser el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como no logre hacerlo funcionar con la sentencia **block** utilice la sentencia **include**. Dejando el directorio de templates con la siguiente estructura

```
  templates/
     |------ body.html
     |------ formulario.html
     |------ index.html
     |------ head.html
```

y los archivos quedaron asi

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
{% include "head.html" %}
{% include "body.html" %} 
{{ premios_globales }}  
</html>
```

head.html:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Consultador de jugadas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/normalize.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}">
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/app.js') }}"></script>
</head>
```

body:

```
<body>
    <div class="contenedor">
        {% include 'formulario.html' %}
    </div>
</body>
```

y del archivo formulario.html solo elimine la instrucciones block y deje el html puro.